# jsの外部参照について

Tags: jquery

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

htmlにjsを外部参照したいのですがページを更新してもjsが動きません。何が悪いのかを教えてもらえると助かります。

Comment: 画像ではなく、テキストでコード全文を提示してください。ブラウザの開発者ツールなどでエラーが出てないか確認してください。どういう動作を期待しているか書いてください。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
この問題は解決しました。
jQueryを使いたかったのですが、jQueryは予めheaderに読み込ませておく必要があることを私が知りませんでした。
現在は、webから読み込ませる方法を取りjQueryが作動する様になりました。
コメントしていただきありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

ソースを画像で貼っておられるので細部まで見えないのですが、

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///Users/user....
```

とfileプロトコルのところ、"/"が3本入っているように見えます。2本にしたら動きませんか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。私の勉強不足でjQueryを使いたい様にしたのですが、jQueryはhtmlに予定読み込みであることがある事を知りませんでした。
そのため、Webで読み込む様にコードを打ち込んだところ作動しました。
答えていただきありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

jQuery を予め読み込んでいませんでした。読み込ませるようにすると動作するようになりました。

<sub>-- [質問者のコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/41689/js%E3%81%AE%E5%A4%96%E9%83%A8%E5%8F%82%E7%85%A7%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6#comment42833_41689)より</sub>